# Improve query performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL. I have a working query in SQL Server Express and it takes around 11 seconds to get the results. I want to improve query performance and I don't have any idea how to make the query faster.

My testing database like

```
dt                       val1
---------              ---------------
2018-01-01 00:00:00     1
2018-01-01 00:01:00     2
2018-01-01 00:02:00     3
so on
```

I'm just try to get daily net value within period.

My query is

```
Select 
    convert(varchar(25), a.dt, 120), (b.val1 - a.val1) as val1 
From 
    testing.dbo.t1 as a, 
    testing.dbo.t1 as b 
where 
    a.dt Between '2018-02-01 00:00:00' and '2018-03-01 00:00:59' 
    and b.dt Between '2018-02-01 00:00:00' and '2018-03-01 00:00:59' 
    and convert(varchar(16), b.dt, 120) = dateadd(day, 1, convert(varchar(16), a.dt, 120)) 
    and convert(varchar(16), a.dt, 120) = dateadd(day, -1, convert(varchar(16), b.dt, 120)) 
    and FORMAT(cast(a.dt as time), N'hh\\:mm') = '00:00' 
    and FORMAT(cast(b.dt as time), N'hh\\:mm') = '00:00' 
order by 
    a.dt
```

Comment: Having names like `val1` and `t1` for your columns certainly won't help us give you an answer. An explanation of what your query does and providing us a schema, among other things, would be super.

Comment: ths, for ur advice.

Comment: Can you show the **table structure**? What columns do you have, and what datatypes are they?? Also: do you have any **Indices** on that table?

Comment: dt(datetime,null), val(bigint,null) only two columns in my test db. But actual db has 54 columns include datetime column and it was recorded every minute. I don't know what you men 'indices on table'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your comments, this is something you're looking for

```
select dt, val1, val1 - lag(val1) over (order by dt) from MY_TABLE
where cast(dt as time) = '00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: Thx Michal, I just try to get daily net values and the column val1 is like total running time(usage of electric power in KWH) of machine or something.

Comment: @ChuArtistmonkey Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Actually I don't really understand your query. But I'd tried yours and the result is not what I want. I want how much kwh or hours of running time day by day for a month. Thank you.

Comment: @ChuArtistmonkey I edited answer to suit your case, but it's only guessing, since you diidn't specify exact expected output...

Comment: Column val1 is total power used by machine(recorded by everyminute). So, If I want to get how much electric power use in one day, I have to subtract val1 where '2018-01-01 00:00:00' from val1 where '2018-01-02 00:00:00'. The result is total electric power used in '2018-01-01 00:00:00' to '2018-01-02 00:00:00'.

Comment: @ChuArtistmonkey I think now the query should solve your issue.

Comment: Thx Michal, that's what I want.

Comment: I google lag/lead and I have learned it. I should use Lead and subtract.

Answer (score 2):

As @jhpratt said his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49217094/improve-query-performance#comment85438227_49217094), it's a little bit difficult task to give a direct answer but I will suggest a point to Improve Query Performance that you can cross verify,

1. I could able to see that you are fetching 1-month data through your query. Does the table has more data in it and If so make sure you have a proper indexing for the column(dt) which are available in WHERE clause.

Also fetching data in 11 seconds is not that much delay and based on the exact requirement, you can fine-tune the query to avoid unwanted Formatting and Conversions that could slow down the execution.